# Error scheduling a bot on Automation Anywhere through admin

Tags: automationanywhere

message":"Error creating RDP session.","details":"This may be due to multiple reasons. To continue, please\n\n1. Please check the number of max session count is configured for this machine\n2. Please find out if no one else has RDP on the machine\n3. Please check that there are no other processes holding RDP connection on the machine\n\nIf you continue to see this message, please contact your system administrator.","correctiveAction":"","code":"rdp.error

I keep getting this error after scheduling the bot, it fails immediately and gives this error

I have tried installing RDP sessions but still does not help

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: There is an issue in scheduling a bot on Automation Anywhere platform, in spite of having admin account this error keeps popping after the bot starts scheduling, hence causing the bot to fail. How do I resolve this